# Use an array in multiple methods

Tags: java, arrays, parameter-passing

I am creating a program with **2 methods**.

In the first method I create an **array**, and in the second method I have to **display** that array **like a table**.

So my question is, how do I create an array in the first method and pass it to the second method for displaying?

```java
public class test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        first();
        second();
    }
    public static void first () {
        int N= (int)(Math.random()*5)+1;
        int M= (int)(Math.random()*5)+1;
        int v [][] = new int [N][M];
        for(int i=0; i < v.length; i++) {
            for(int j=0; j < v[0].length; j++) {
                v [i][j]= (int)(Math.random()*5);
            }
        }
    }
    public static void second () {
        for(int i=0; i < v.length; i++) { 
            for(int j=0; j < v[0].length; j++)
                System.out.print(v [i][j] + " ");
            System.out.println("");
        }
    }
}
```

how can I pass the array "v" in the second method?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you show us your code? Are you getting any specific errors?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) or how to improve the quality of your question. Then edit your question to include your full source code you have as a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), which can be compiled and tested by others.

Comment: Use parameters and return values. Start here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the first method calls the second method, just pass it as parameter:

```
public void doStuff(){
    int[] arr;//initialize
    useArray(arr);
}
public void useArray(int[] arr){
     //use it
}
```

If both methods are ececuted one after another, return it, save it to a variable and pass it:

```
public void outerMethod(){
    int[] arr=createArray();
    useArray(arr);
}
public int[] createArray(){
    int[] arr;
    //initialize it
    return arr;
}
public void useArray(int[] arr){
    //use arr
}
```

In your case, this would be:

```java
public class test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] v=first();
        second(v);
    }
    public static int[][] first () {
        int N= (int)(Math.random()*5)+1;
        int M= (int)(Math.random()*5)+1;
        int v [][] = new int [N][M];
        for(int i=0; i < v.length; i++) {
            for(int j=0; j < v[0].length; j++) {
                v [i][j]= (int)(Math.random()*5);
            }
        }
        return v;
    }
    public static void second (int[][] v) {
        for(int i=0; i < v.length; i++) { 
            for(int j=0; j < v[0].length; j++)
                System.out.print(v [i][j] + " ");
            System.out.println("");
        }
    }
}
```

[**Notes**]

This does not only work with integer arrays but also any other array.

In fact, this works with any type.

By convention, class names should be written PascalCase and variable (and method) names should be written camelCase.

Comment: Thanks you. you are right.

Comment: I would appreciate you accepting my answer if I helped you.